# C# DllImport help (Mac Os)

Tags: c#, macos, interop, dllimport

I'm developing an app in Mac Os X in C# (with mono), I need to interop with some functions, but I don't know how can I do this..

I've made a simple app in C, but now I need to do the same in C#, I know that i should use DllImport, but I don't know how can I do this..

The function that I want to call in C# is this one:

```
mach_vm_read(vm_map_t target_task, mach_vm_address_t address, mach_vm_size_t size, vm_offset_t *data. mach_msg_type_number_t *data_count);
```

is defined in one of those files

```
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_vm.h>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you import functions from a Win32 DLL in MacOS X? Very curious to know if this is even possible - I thought Mono was based on native implementations of the CLR and .NET class libraries?

Comment: Well, the function that I want to import is not from a Win32 DLL, its from a MacOs lib, I reed somewhere in Mono website, that I should use DllImport to call unmanaged libraries (even if they are not Win32 libraries), they also recommend the use of Swig to interop with unmanaged code, but I don't think I need to use that, I only need to call one function..

Answer (score 2):

This page is going to be the most useful for you:

[Interop with Native Libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries)

In general, P/Invoke on OS X / Linux in Mono works just like it does on Windows.

Comment: This link was super helpful to me, because the linked-to page contained the information that while on Windows the name of the dll is 'dllname.dll', on MacOs the name of the dll is 'libdllname.dylib', and I was able to import a function from my dynamic library written the rust language.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare and call the method in C# by decorating the method call with the [DllImport()] attribute, like so (provided your method you want to call is indeed a static method, and has no return type):

```
[DllImport("YourDll.dll")]
public static extern void mach_vm_read(vm_map_t target_task, mach_vm_address_t address, mach_vm_size_t size, vm_offset_t *data. mach_msg_type_number_t *data_count);
```

Comment: thanks for answering so quick, but how can I map those C structs (vm_map_t, mach_vm_address_t...) to classes or something in C#?
(sorry if I'm being such a noob..)

Comment: I think you should read about interop, but I'm not sure if it works the same on mono and macosx..

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of c++ you can use a tool called [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) to generate a C# wrapper for all of your exposed c++ functions using simple templates. We have used this to great success on Windows, Mac OS and Linux.